# why the move constructor/move assignment are not implicitly declared and defined as deleted if we only define copy constructor/oper=?

Tags: c++, c++11

As per the C++ standard 12.8.7:

> If the class definition declares a move constructor or move
>   assignment  operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor is
>   defined as deleted;

and 12.8.18

> If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment
>   operator, the implicitly declared copy assignment operator is defined
>   as  deleted;

I am wondering why the move constructor/move assignment are not implicitly declared and defined as deleted (c++11 standard will not generate implicitly declared move constructor/move assignment in this case), if we only defined copy constructor or copy assignment operator?

Comment: There's no "implicitly declared move constructor/move assignment" if you declare a copy constructor or copy assignment operator.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, I have revised the question.

Comment: From the sample code of Angew, I guess one of the main reason is to back-compatible with the legacy code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this was the case, then using an rvalue as the source of construction or assginment would result in a compilation error instead of falling back to a copy.

A function which does not exist (obviously) does not participate in overload resolution. A function which is defined as deleted *does* participate in overload resolution normally; if it's chosen, the compilation results in an error.

This code [compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a8adc216cbd1e8c):

```
struct Normal
{
    Normal() {}

    Normal(const Normal &) {}
};


int main()
{
    Normal n(Normal{});
}
```

While this code [results in an error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27ba0ac9fe74cbd8):

```
struct Deleted
{
    Deleted() {}

    Deleted(const Deleted &) {}

    Deleted(Deleted&&) = delete;
};


int main()
{
    Deleted d(Deleted{});
}
```

Comment: There's also the weird case of defaulted-that-is-defined-as-deleted move ctors/assignment operators, which are ignored by overload resolution.

Comment: @T.C. I don't think these are "ignored." I was under the impression the wording was "if it was defined as deleted, it is instead not declared at all."

Comment: See the last sentences of [class.copy]/p11 and p23. They are ignored.

Comment: @T.C. Sorry, I can't seem to find it in C++11 (in the points you posted) Which standard version?

Comment: I was referring to N4140. Let me check N3337. (Edit - ah, I see, it had a "would not be defined as deleted" in there.)

Answer (score 3):

If the move constructor were deleted in that case, then trying to copy-initialise from an *rvalue* would be an error - the deleted move constructor would be a better match than the copy constructor.

Usually, you'd want copy-initialisation to copy, rather than be disallowed, if you haven't defined move semantics. To give that behaviour, the move constructor is simply not declared at all, so that copy-initialisation uses the copy constructor whether copying from an *lvalue* or an *rvalue*. (As long as the copy constructor takes its argument by `const` reference.)

You can still delete the move operations yourself, if for some reason you want the rather odd quality of only being copyable from an *lvalue*.